# adding animated GIF to swing label

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, jlabel

```
public void run(){
        Icon reel = common.ResourcesToAccess.reel;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(reel);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setSize(reel.getIconWidth(),reel.getIconHeight());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try{
            sleep(2*1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
        frame.dispose();
    }
```

I tried typing `reel.setImageObserver(label);` but Eclipse flags that statement as an error. Why?
What else can I do to display animation ?

---

Update:  New Code:

```
@Override
    public void run(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon reel = (ImageIcon) common.ResourcesToAccess.reel;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(reel);
        reel.setImageObserver(label);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**although I could set the ImageObserver here, GIF still does not animate**

### Misc:

The GIF I am using can be found here:
http://bestanimations.com/Electronics/Video/Video.html
It is the one right above the television on the right. The spinning reel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By sleeping for 2 seconds in the EDT, you prevent it from doing its work (like repainting the GUI and displaying your animated gif). Remove the call to `Thread.sleep()`.

If you want the frame to close itself after 2 seconds, use a `javax.swing.Timer` to schedule the closing after 2 seconds.

Comment: @JB Nizet: check the new code. All the magic is in run(), the variables u see are all the variables that are there

Comment: Works fine here, except it spins much faster than in the web page. Also, you don't need to call `reel.setImageObserver(label)`.

Comment: If you want more help (or find where the problem is by yourself), write an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. In this SSCCE, assume that the gif file is called animated.gif and is in the classpath, in the same package as your SSCCE class. Download a fresh copy of the gif to run your SSCCE, just as if you were us. I did that, and it runs fine. So the problem might be elsewhere in the code, or in the animated gif, or in the way you're constructing the ImageIcon.

Answer (score 3):

`What else can I do to display animation ?`

Well here I have done a short and simple EG to show how you can add an image to `JLabel`.I have used `JApplet`, you can modify this as per your needs.

[image]

**CODE:**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JLabelWithIconExample extends JApplet
 {


    public void init(){

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("e:/guitar.gif");/*your path*/

        JLabel copyLabel = new JLabel(icon);
                    add(copyLabel);

                       }
 }
```

Comment: For some reason, if you get your `ImageIcon` object with something like this `Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("iconasresource.gif")));` your GIF won't get animated

Comment: @jaime then try giving full path?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are attempting to show an animated GIF while some background task is being executed? Check out 
SwingWorker to learn more about background task, instead of carrying out long running tasks on the EDT (event dispatch thread).

Comment: No, to test the code, I am using a main method. So  no bg task